# Opening text file from subdirectory

Tags: python, text-files

I want to open a text file that is in the main directory from a subdirectory:

Python file: project/subdirectory/load_file.py

Text file: project/file.txt

This is how I want to load it but it's not finding the file:

```
with open("./project/token.txt", "r") as f:
     print(f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```py
with open("../token.txt", "r") as f:
     print(f)
```